# Install Jupyter on Centos

Tags: centos, python

so I've got Python 2.7 properly install on CentOS, with pip configured to install packages on a custom location.
Everything has worked so far, but now I'm installing Jupyter like so:

```
pip install jupyter
```

And I get this output:

```
Collecting jupyter
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Using cached notebook-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Using cached ipywidgets-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Using cached nbconvert-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Using cached ipykernel-4.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Using cached jupyter_console-4.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Using cached qtconsole-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting traitlets (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached traitlets-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting tornado>=4 (from notebook->jupyter)
Collecting jupyter-client (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached jupyter_client-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting nbformat (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached nbformat-4.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jupyter-core (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached jupyter_core-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting terminado>=0.3.3 (from notebook->jupyter)
Collecting ipython-genutils (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached ipython_genutils-0.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jinja2 (from notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipython>=4.0.0dev0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached ipython-4.1.2-py2-none-any.whl
Collecting pygments (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached Pygments-2.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mistune!=0.6 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Using cached mistune-0.7.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator (from traitlets->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached decorator-4.0.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting certifi (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached certifi-2016.2.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports-abc>=0.4 (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached backports_abc-0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting backports.ssl-match-hostname (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
Collecting singledispatch (from tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached singledispatch-3.4.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyzmq>=13 (from jupyter-client->notebook->jupyter)
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.0 (from nbformat->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ptyprocess (from terminado>=0.3.3->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached ptyprocess-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MarkupSafe (from jinja2->notebook->jupyter)
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython>=4.0.0dev0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached pickleshare-0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython>=4.0.0dev0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
Collecting setuptools>=18.5 (from ipython>=4.0.0dev0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached setuptools-20.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pexpect (from ipython>=4.0.0dev0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
Collecting six (from singledispatch->tornado>=4->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting functools32 (from jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.0->nbformat->notebook->jupyter)
Collecting path.py>=6.2 (from pickleshare->ipython>=4.0.0dev0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Using cached path.py-8.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: decorator, ipython-genutils, traitlets, certifi, backports-abc, backports.ssl-match-hostname, six, singledispatch, tornado, jupyter-core, pyzmq, jupyter-client, functools32, jsonschema, nbformat, pygments, mistune, MarkupSafe, jinja2, nbconvert, path.py, pickleshare, simplegeneric, setuptools, ptyprocess, pexpect, ipython, ipykernel, terminado, notebook, ipywidgets, jupyter-console, qtconsole, jupyter
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-0.23 backports-abc-0.4 backports.ssl-match-hostname-3.5.0.1 certifi-2016.2.28 decorator-4.0.9 functools32-3.2.3.post2 ipykernel-4.3.1 ipython-4.1.2 ipython-genutils-0.1.0 ipywidgets-4.1.1 jinja2-2.8 jsonschema-2.5.1 jupyter jupyter-client-4.2.1 jupyter-console-4.1.1 jupyter-core-4.0.6 mistune-0.7.2 nbconvert-4.1.0 nbformat-4.0.1 notebook-4.1.0 path.py-8.1.2 pexpect-4.0.1 pickleshare-0.6 ptyprocess-0.5.1 pygments-2.1.3 pyzmq-15.2.0 qtconsole-4.2.0 setuptools-20.2.2 simplegeneric-0.8.1 singledispatch-3.4.0.3 six-1.10.0 terminado-0.6 tornado-4.3 traitlets-4.1.0
```

But my problem is that even though pip says everything went well with the install, I don't get the jupyter command line tool. If I run jupyter from the command line, I get "command not found". 
Any ideas why this might be happening?

**Edit with more info**

Shell used: bash

Output from `type jupyter`:

```
bash: type: jupyter: not found
```

Results from `find / -name jupyter`: nothing found

Comment: Can you normally install something like that, and then just run it?  Have you logged out and logged in again?  What shell are you using?  What happens if you say `type jupyter`?  How about `find / -name jupyter`?

Comment: Possible (cross-site) duplicate of [Why does bash say No such file or directory when the file is on the path?](http://superuser.com/q/1016130/354511)

Comment: Hey @G-Man thanks for the reply, I've added more info to answer your questions. As for the duplicate, I don't think it is, since I don't have the executable anywhere on my system.

Comment: How about `ls -la /usr/local/bin/jupyter`?

Comment: @Deleteman: Thanks for responding. If `find` didn't find anything, that indicates that `pip` did not install a program called `jupyter`; so you're right: the other question is unrelated to your situation. I'm very knowledgeable about Unix, but I don't know Python, and I've never heard of Jupyter, so I probably won't be able to help you — except to say that Unix&Linux might not be the best community for this question. Quite possibly the question will be closed soon. If it doesn't get answered first, and it doesn't get migrated, you might want to click on "flag" and ask a mod to migrate it.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I get this output: ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/jupyter: No such file or directory

Comment: thanks @G-Man, to which community do you think it would be best to migrate it? Development?

Comment: Good question; I'm not sure.  The "obvious" choices are [SO] and [SU], but Stack Exchange has over 150 communities now, and I make no effort to learn about the new ones as they are added.  I suggest that you visit the [Stack Exchange Sites List](http://stackexchange.com/sites#name) and try to find a suitable one.

Comment: Did you try restarting the machine?

Comment: @CryptoJones sadly I can't do that, I don't have that kind of control over the server. Also, if I install it on my local computer, it works right out of the bat, only diff is my local has Ubuntu and the server has CentOS.

Comment: Try reloading your bash profile by running 'source ~/.bash_profile'

Comment: @CryptoJones I can, but it's not a path issue, the file is not created. I did a find over the entire disk, and there is no "jupyter" script anywhere.

Comment: Sorry @Deleteman I misunderstood the question.